# How to optimise my code efficiency to speed up large data file extraction programs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently engaged with a data science project, I am trying to get to grips with improving code efficiency, so that my code runs at a faster rate so it can get through lots of sample data. I have provided the piece of code which I wish for comments on.

Currently to try and optimise my code I have looked into numpy arrays, I have looked into loops, have looked into list comprehensions, where suitable I have tried to implement them. However because of my basic background in coding I require aid in seeing other possible methods to speed up my code.

```
chromosomefragmentlist=[]
Number_of_fragments=150
ChromosomeNumber=1
FragmentSize=1000000
for i in range(0, (Number_of_fragments), 1):
    a = ("Chromosome" + str(ChromosomeNumber) + "Fragment" + str(i) + ",Basepairs " + 
         str(i * FragmentSize + 1) + "-" + str(i * FragmentSize + FragmentSize))
    chromosomefragmentlist.append(str(Dict.get((a))))
return(chromosomefragmentlist)
```

How do I make this more efficient? This code will result in a list, I am more interested in making it run faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can't be "boosted", cause anyway you have to iterate over range and get values from dict. Small speed up you can achieve using list comprehension instead, but it's not significant.

I recommend you to read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and use recommended coding style. Applying it to your current code you should rename variables:

- `ChromosomeNumber` **->** `chromosome_num`.

  > Variable names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability
- `FragmentSize` **->** `fragment_size`;
- `Number_of_fragments` **->** `fragments_len` (*len* is shorten variant of *length*);
- `Dict` **->** `some_dict` (you should replace *some* with proper keyword; also you should avoid naming variables with names of python's built-in types, functions, modules, etc.);
- `chromosomefragmentlist` **->** `chromosomes`.

Other recommendations:

- `range(0, (Number_of_fragments), 1)` is equivalent of `range(Number_of_fragments)` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range));
- It'll be better to use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) instead of string concatenation;
- It's more common to use `some_dict[key]` syntax instead of [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method if you don't need to return default value if key doesn't exist.

Using all recommendations you'll get next code:

```
fmt = "Chromosome{}Fragment{},Basepairs {}-{}"
return [some_dict[fmt.format(chromosome_num, i, i * fragment_size + 1, i * fragment_size + fragment_size)]
        for i in range(fragments_len)]
```

Comment: Olvin Roght That's unfortunate that I cannot boost my code. A small speed up will impact my program.